# For-loops: How to handle three iterative variables in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, iteration

Here's a minimal representation of the problem. Let's say I have a matrix `Y`, and I'm trying to populate a matrix `X` based on operations I perform on the elements in `Y`. Because `Y` is a large matrix, I want to populate `X` matrix in the same in one for-loop (in order to save time & less data structures to deal with). Here's what I have so far. Assume the condition of my first for-loop is correct and necessary.

```
Y<- matrix(nrow= 109, ncol = 10064)
X<- matrix(nrow= 109, ncol = 10058)
k<- 1

# I want to start at the 7th column of Y and skip every other column
for (j in seq(7, 10058, 2)){ # this is how I want it to loop; this loops 5029 times

# assign new_values based on the column pairs in Y; ie look in each column pairf of Y 
# and create new values based on the columns pairs in Y: Y[,j] and Y[,j+1]

 for (i in 1:109){
    #if (Y[i,j] == new_value_1){
    #   X[i,k]<- 0
    #}
    #else if (Y[i,j] == new_value_2){
    #   X[i,k]<- 1
    #}
    #else if (Y[i,j] == new_value_3){
    #   X[i,k]<- 2
    #}
  }
 k<- k + 1
}
```

The contents in matrices `X` and `Y` aren't important. The `new_values` aren't important. It's the **indexing** in matrix `X` that I need help with. If you run the code above, you'll notice that at the end of the loop `i` is `109` (which is correct) but `k` is only iterating up to `5027` or `5028`. In other words, the code is only populating *half* of the matrix. I want k to iterate up to `10058` so that I can populate matrix `X` correctly. Can someone help me fix this? thanks

Comment: Let's say you're on column `j = 9`. Should this column in `X` be the same as the 8th column or the 10th column? Or is the method for filling the other half of the columns completely different from anything you've put in your actual question?

Comment: And while we're at it, why bother with the inner loop at all when you could use `ifelse`?

Comment: `X` is a completely new matrix. It shouldn't be the same as the 8th or 10th column of `Y`. The method for filling the other half of the columns of `X` is the same throughout. I would like to know how to iterate k so that it goes up to 10058 and fills in all the elements in `X`

Comment: No, you misunderstood. Your j loop will only ever happen 5028 times. That means if you want to do something to the other columns, you'll have to repeat your inner loop (gah! the inefficiencies!) and use either k+1 or k-1. I was trying to determine which you wanted, k+1 or k-1. (But really. Use `ifelse` instead.)

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean. I think I want `k+1`. Hmmm, I've never used `ifelse` in `R` before. How would I use it to fill in the entire `X` matrix?

Comment: thanks @joran! I revised the code to get it working the way I wanted to. See my answer below. Later when you're free, can you post how I would apply `ifselse` to this problem? thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know how to apply `ifelse` to this problem, this seemed to do the trick.

```
Y<- matrix(nrow= 109, ncol = 10064)
X<- matrix(nrow= 109, ncol = 10058)
k<- 1

for (j in seq(7, 10058, 2)){
    for (o in 1:2){
        for (i in 1:109){

        }
     }
   k<- k+1
   }
 }
```

At the end of the loop `k` is now `10058` like I wanted. And `i` is still `109`.